# When to use -는 도중에 vs -는 동안(에)

Tags: grammar

Can you please explain me the difference between using -는 도중에 and -는 동안(에)? I know, that they both mean "while", but can't figure out how to use them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Korean often uses both them such like, 
           그는 학교를 가는 도중에 친구를 만났다. (He met a friend on his way to school.)
           그는 학교를 가는 동안에 친구를 만났다. (He met a friend while going to school.)

However, technically, there are some subtle differences.

-는 도중에 means 'on one's way to'. 도중 means one's way. 
'는 동안에 relates to 'time intervals'. from one moment to another moment.

Korean would not severely distinguish -는 도중에 and -는 동안(에).
But, to speak naturally, let me show u some examples.

내가 점심을 먹는 동안(에) 쉬고 있어.(Take a break while I have a lunch.) 
=> Good
내가 점심을 먹는 도중에 쉬고 있어.=> Something strange, but still possible to understand.

학교를 가는 동안에 빵을 샀다. => Good.
학교를 가는 도중에 빵을 샀다. => Good.

4년 동안 => Good!
4년 도중 => Nope!

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation! It's like a chapter of a good grammar book.